# fast array conversion using different definitions for TPolygon

Tags: delphi

I use these definitions within my applications for a point and a polygon:

```
type 
   FPoint = record
    X: Real;
    Y: Real;
    end; 
 TFPolygon = array of FPoint;
```

what is the shortest conversion option  for my array
**TFPolygon into a TPolygon array** ?
`Type TPolygon` is defined  inside System.Math.Vectors as :

```
  TPolygon = array of TPointF;
```

I know, a loop  can do this, any faster and shorter option ?

Usecase :
FXM graphics accepts polygon with  TPolygon definition, in VCL we  paint using integer points as polgon elements.

Comment: Ask yourself - is your `Real` really `Double`, `Single`, or ancient `Real48`? What does `F` denote in `TPointF` - is it `Single` or `Double`?

Comment: From integer  to  Single I will not use any  information.  a transfer  is basically possible

Comment: Why integer? `Real` is a float type, but true type (4/6/8 bytes size) depends on your compiler settings, so we cannot say what to do without your check-up.